# How do I keep my WordPress content in a private git repository?

Tags: juju, git, wordpress

I have got my wordpress up and running. Now I want the wp-content to sync with my private git. How do I modify the following code to include username and password to my private git?

```
juju set wordpress wp-content=git@host:path/repo.git
```

My git repo is on codebasehq.com. Also it would be nice if I can just version control the plugin and themes directory not the whole wp-content which includes wp-uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys at codebasehq were kind enough to let me know how to write the URL in the juju so it would pick up a private git.

The following should work for anyone he is wondering how to use a private git.

```
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@project.codebasehq.com/wordpress/wp-content.git
```